# FutureProvider: How I can build error screen using catchError

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'am using provider pattern for my app. I try to implement alternative error screen by using FutureProvider. I am use an api call. If api call returns with fail, I want to see an error screen like in FutureBuilder. But nothing comes out. I don't see any changes on the screen. It ignores error checking. But the error is visible in the console.

Code:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool checkError = false;
    return FutureProvider(
      lazy: false,
      create: (context) =>
          Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: false).getData(),
      updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,
      catchError: (context, error) {
        checkError = true;
      },
      child: checkError
          ? Center(
              child: Text('Something went wrong. Try later.'),
            ): DataList(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: As a first idea, your `bool checkError = false;` should reside *outside* of the build function.

Comment: I can't use non final variable in the class, because I'm use statelessWidget.

Comment: But your widget appears to have state.

Comment: I really wouldn't like to change the widget to StatefulWidget. I need any solution without this. I use checkError variable just because I don't know other solutions.

Comment: Are you sure you did not confuse `FutureProvider` with `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: I try to find an alternative to `FutureBuilder` just because I'm use navigation bar which reload content of pages every time when I change the tab. and therefore `FutureBuilder` reruns each time, when I change page. By using  `FutureProvider` I was able to avoid this unnecessary reloads.

Comment: Sounds like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It might be more effective to ask your actual question instead of jumping to a solution and struggling with it, giving it artificial restraints.

Comment: I tried to find a solution here on the forum and by googling. But the solutions didn't solve the problem. I had to look for an alternative.